# What do we do with the OIDC Auth Token? Cache it or send it to the User Agent?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

We're truly struggling with understanding how OIDC is suppossed to work in B2C (or OIDC by any provider for that matter).

We think we understand (some) parts of the protocol...but are utterly confused by other parts.

Wondering if anyone could look at the following diagram, and (hopefully) correct post a correction.

The questions we have are:

- Is it correct to create the Session Record before sending the User to the IdP, and saving the Session record Guid id as the Nonce?

  - Will the Nonce remain the same over reissuing of tokens?
  - Any chance of that turning into a DoS attack vector, pounding away at a protected resource url? Or should a WAF be used to stop requests earlier?
- We've argued this for a while now -- but is the Auth_Token obtained from the IdP private, and should not be shared with the User Agent (in other words, is it an *IdP* Session Token, as oppossed to an *App* Session Token)?

  - And if it is private, should we be sending back an App Session Token, generated on the Server?
- But to call another Service, we should be caching the Auth_Token we got back, so we can use it to call ServiceB? (or we totally up the wrong tree now?)
- When ServiceB fails the call (eg, not enough Scopes), what then? Does ServiceA send the UserAgent back to the IdP, where it gets issued a new Auth_Token, which the Client (ie, ServiceA) uses to replace its previously cached Auth_Token, and tries to invoke ServiceB again?
- Finally (and we've had lots of arguments about this). Is the ServiceA suppossed to return a Cookie *AND* a BearerToken so that the Client can use the BearerToken for subsequent APIs calls...or should the Client be using a Cookie to authenticate itself when invoking APIs of ServiceA?

We know that this is a lot of questions. But we couldn't think of a way to break the issues we're facing into smaller sets of discrete problems. The whole thing is currently confusing to us.

Thanks. Very much.

The Sequence Diagram we built so far is viewable here:

[image]

PS: If it helps the above image can be re-edited and re-embedded from here (the text/image links at the bottom of the image):

[Source DSL](https://www.planttext.com/?text=TLHDZzem4BtdLupsi89LsyCUEPH2s4fSbXNGMwJAjGTYaTYfxS3VxuppGKApEKJ1y-RDcpTZVlWWNAZB8g4dw50WxBQR50xujqOZCKc43DR1BuykgGYgfQw42V2qTlP6XqyWV8okpcZ26790TzKICpCBEK9QQ4BCOq8R6S7tgBGVdMpLnvXmHpmkCstsaEarINeHyFLxTmmBSDo93vbnz7Owe8gVjdPKluEDCjuj17j1iuHZZWQaGn4G3Duoiweg0dglhI5YQPrAZAMWq-SyW3rrB0lOsCFoJa_yTtciIMbA3rI7cypCJOUyDMXB-eHHC2ob5RVwRdaWWpQ9bRA9Js6Xh-XwXWY2Flnc0WUfAaMrA7p2vu-YzdTHlSMjifMKf0HIgnxhtrtRj1g6s67_ZPGfL2VcphN7K3lJWOuyZEbH_TJa52lAp3wE0qxEbfdnzHzW4ya-DPsfJpnHg2dtIpVYw5h3CvsKsnkFJ2X5LWjTUlxLxCfqWl3UIjrp4xeRwLR1xAf5CzJvj-dqL4YwEB7_9NVOk5A7_7SyuwL8hRrecjCBjVi2QnIEwXmV9FstVapaQSzWTbodymQV6TfVRqk42xdwsNKgnGKzpF2yO25Msh8gCE0SLXzRaA8eClCC7idxHaiZbFv16g6V-CHp95QkJXxFUV-6bompqVRUp7WNMyYkGYS2VKmmln9rr2BPIDNvyWy0)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-php-webapp-openidconnect) which shows how token verification logic works with OpenID Connect and B2C.

> Is it correct to create the Session Record before sending the User to
>   the IdP, and saving the Session record Guid id as the Nonce?

Yes, this should be correct.

> Will the Nonce remain the same over reissuing of tokens?

I am not entirely sure what you mean but the value will remain unmodified in the nonce claim of an ID token, so yes it should.

See [also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc) >

It might be worth calling up customer support for your case as there are a lot of questions that might be best directed towards the product team. I'll be following up with these questions and getting back to you.